# How to sort a date file with AM|PM

Tags: bash, sorting

I have a file with date field like this.

```
20|1|124|Mar 19 2016  3:00AM
20|1|144|Mar 19 2016  2:00PM
43|1|146|Mar 19 2016  5:30AM
42|1|158|Mar 19 2016  1:50PM
40|1|15|Mar 19 2016  2:30AM
```

I want to sort by date field, such that the AM will come before PM. so far I have this:

```
sort -t"|" -k4 testfile.
```

But i am not sure how to sort the "AM" and "PM" portion. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bash sort - how do I sort using timestamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17844072/bash-sort-how-do-i-sort-using-timestamp)

Comment: I suggest to use a [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
while read -r; do
   IFS='|' read -ra arr <<< "$REPLY"
   date -d "${arr[-1]}" "+$REPLY#%s"
done < file | sort -t# -k2 | cut -d# -f1

40|1|15|Mar 19 2016  2:30AM
20|1|124|Mar 19 2016  3:00AM
43|1|146|Mar 19 2016  5:30AM
42|1|158|Mar 19 2016  1:50PM
20|1|144|Mar 19 2016  2:00PM
```

Using `date` command we parse last field in your pipe delimited field and add EPOCH value in each line delimited by `#`. Then using `sort` we do the sorting by 2nd field (EPOCH value) and finally using `cut` we discard value after `#`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a temporary delimiter (ie `|`) to make `AM`/`PM` a column that can be used as a sort field :

```
$ cat sourcefile | sed 's/\(.\)M$/|\1M/' | sort -t"|" -k5 -k4 | sed 's/|\(.\)M/\1M/'
40|1|15|Mar 19 2016  2:30AM
20|1|124|Mar 19 2016  3:00AM
43|1|146|Mar 19 2016  5:30AM
42|1|158|Mar 19 2016  1:50PM
20|1|144|Mar 19 2016  2:00PM
```